# Script won't run properly in Task Manager but runs fine manually

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I wrote this script which functions 100% perfectly when I run it manually in ISE or otherwise but it doesn't run properly when launched from a scheduled task.

It won't delete files from the local machine or copy files to the library server for longtime storage...but it creates the perfmon files on the local machine just fine.

I was initially using PSDrive to map a path but then I just hard coded it after reading that you can't seem to use PSDrive via Task Scheduler.

```
# Setting variables and creating directories

$FileDate = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy-hh-mm-ss"
$EmailDateStart = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd-hh:mm:ss"
$Counters = '\Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use','\Processor Information(_Total)\% Processor Time'
$Interval = '5'
$Samples = '60' # There are 720 samples at 5 seconds per sample in an hour, 60 in 5     
$FileDir = "C:\Utilities\CPU_RAM_Stats\Files"
$BLGPath = "$FileDir\$env:COMPUTERNAME-CPU_RAM_Stats_$FileDate.blg"                                                                 
$BLGFiles = dir $FileDir # Checking local server directory for list of .blg files
$LibPath = "\\<IP>\d$\CPU_RAM_Stats\$env:COMPUTERNAME" # Destination path of .blg files on Library server

# Creating destination folder on Library server if it doesn't exist

if (!(Test-Path $LibPath))
{
    New-Item "\\<IP>\d$\CPU_RAM_Stats\$env:COMPUTERNAME" -type Directory
}

<# ========================= DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS POINT ========================= #>

# Checking existing log file to see if it's over whatever size was specified above (in KB). If so, deleting file and recreating.

Write-Host "Cleaning up BLG files on Library server to maintain folder size..."

Get-ChildItem $LibPath -Recurse -Include *.blg  | Where{-not $_.PsIsContainer} | Sort CreationTime -desc | Select -Skip 500 | Remove-Item -Force

# Checking for existence of files in the library server and deleting from PRD server to keep directories clean, otherwise uploading

foreach ($BLGFile in $BLGFiles)
{            
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host $(Get-Date) "[ACTION][CHECKING BACKUP] Checking if" $BLGFile.name "has been previously uploaded to the library server" -ForegroundColor Gray
    if (Test-Path "$LibPath\$BLGFile")
    {
        Write-Host $(Get-Date) "[ACTION][BACKED UP]" $BLGFile.name "has been previously uploaded to the library server" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $Removal = Remove-Item "$FileDir\$BLGFile"
        $Removal
        Write-Host $(Get-Date) "[ACTION][DELETED]" $BLGFile.name "has been deleted from the PRD server" -ForegroundColor Magenta
        Write-Host ""
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host $(Get-Date) "[ACTION][NOT BACKED UP]" $BLGFile.name "has NOT been previously uploaded to the library server...continuing to upload" -ForegroundColor Green

        # Starting main process of checking for locked files and uploading them

        $FilePath = "$FileDir\$BLGFile"
        Write-Host $(Get-Date) "[ACTION][FILECHECK] Checking if" $BLGFile.name "is locked" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $FileInfo = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $FilePath

        try 
        {
            $fileStream = $fileInfo.Open( [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read, [System.IO.FileShare]::Read )
            Write-Host $(Get-Date) "[ACTION][FILEAVAILABLE]" $BLGFile.name "is not locked and available for upload" -ForegroundColor Green
            if ($true)
            {
                Write-Host  $(Get-Date) "Uploading:" $BLGFile.name -ForegroundColor Cyan
                Write-Host ""

                Write-Host "Uploading to library server..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
                Write-Host ""
                Copy-Item "$FileDir\$BLGFile" "$LibPath"
                Write-Host $(Get-Date) "[ACTION][COMPLETE] Upload complete!" -ForegroundColor Green
            }
            Write-Host ""
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host $(Get-Date) "[ACTION][FILELOCKED]" $BLGFile.name " is locked, not uploaded" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
}

# Running PerfMon to gather CPU/RAM stats

$Results = Get-Counter -Counter $Counters -SampleInterval $Interval -MaxSamples $Samples | Export-Counter -Path $BLGPath -Force -FileFormat "BLG"
```

---

**EDIT/UPDATE: 12/21/17**

Looks like it's because I was running the scheduled task as "SYSTEM"...when I changed it to my user account, it worked fine. How can I get this to run the task under "SYSTEM" so I don't need to provide a password to my account for the task?

Comment: The SYSTEM account doesn't have access to the network share you're trying to access, your user account apparently does. Recommendation is to not use SYSTEM anymore. Use LOCAL SERVICE if the task needs only access to local resources. Use NETWORK SERVICE if the task needs access to publicly accessible network resources (or uses credentials stored in the script or a config file). Use your own (or a dedicated) user account if the task needs access to network resources with implicit authentication (where Windows automatically authenticates with the current user's credentials).

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers, I ended up just using a standard 'net use' and leaving it as System.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AnsgarWiechers, I ended up just using a standard 'net use' with an account and leaving it as System in task scheduler. Was trying to avoid doing it that way but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a specific  user for this process ?

Anyway you can encrypt the password :
https://www.interworks.com/blog/trhymer/2013/07/08/powershell-how-encrypt-and-store-credentials-securely-use-automation-scripts

Or You can convert the PowerShell to exe to hide the password .